# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined" error in jest with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, expo

I have used expo-apple-authentication library, which is causing error while creating snapshot with jest.

Error

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

      at requireNativeViewManager (node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/src/NativeViewManagerAdapter.native.tsx:28:49)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-apple-authentication/src/ExpoAppleAuthenticationButton.ts:15:46)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-apple-authentication/src/AppleAuthenticationButton.tsx:8:1)
```

jest.config.js

```
// jest.config.js
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require("ts-jest/presets");
const { setupFiles } = require("@testing-library/react-native/jest-preset");

module.exports = {
   preset: "jest-expo",
   globals: {
      "ts-jest": {
         tsconfig: "tsconfig.spec.json",
      },
   },
   transform: {
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest",
   },
   transformIgnorePatterns: [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)",
   ],
   moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
   modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["./server"],
   setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/components/utils/jestSetup.ts", ...setupFiles],
};
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
   api.cache(true);
   return {
      presets: ["babel-preset-expo", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
   };
};
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
// tsconfig.spec.json
{
   "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
   "compilerOptions": {
     "jsx": "react"
   }
 }
```

I am new to jest, it would be great if someone help me with this.

**Edited:**

jestSetup.ts

```
import Analytics from "./analytics";
import Global from "./global";

jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.mock("./analytics", () => ({
   Analytics: jest.fn(),
}));
jest.mock("./global", () => ({
   Global: jest.fn(),
}));
```

test file

```
//LaunchScreen.test.tsx
import React from "react";
import { create } from "react-test-renderer";
import LaunchScreen from "../screens/LaunchScreen";

const tree = create(<LaunchScreen />);

jest.runAllTimers();

test("LaunchScreen snapshot", () => {
   expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

imports of LaunchScreen.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {
   View,
   StyleSheet,
   TouchableOpacity,
   Alert,
   Linking,
   Image,
   Dimensions,
   Platform,
   SafeAreaView,
   TextInput,
   Modal,
} from "react-native";

import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";
import { GoogleSigninButton } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as AppleAuthentication from "expo-apple-authentication";

//other code of this file...
```

I also created "**mocks**" folder which have mock of "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and "react-native-device-info"

Comment: Could you please share the test file you are trying to run? I need to see what you are mocking etc.

Comment: Thank you @Marcus for your comment, I have added a few more files that you have asked for, below 'Edited'.

Comment: So what's going on here is that one of your mocks needs to be amended to supply an array to the `requireNativeViewManager` method of `NativeViewManagerAdapter`. You need to find the place in your code where that is being passed through.

Comment: @Marcus According to the error, that code where requireNativeViewManager is used is somewhere in expo-apple-authentication lib. Can you tell me how to mock this function?